# I'm trying to correlate numbers in an array of arrays to an object with a list of filenames listed in categories

Tags: javascript

***Note:*** *My code works properly. This is a conceptual question about program design rather than directly about broken code.*

I've got a array of arrays. `set = [[28, 12, 14], [34, 83, 89], [78, 34, 29]]`

Separately, I have a JSON file that has a list of filenames, defined in 3 categories.

```
{
    "main": [
        {"id": "main001", "src": "main001.png"},
        {"id": "main002", "src": "main002.png"},
        ...
        {"id": "main098", "src": "main098.png"}
    ],
    "corner": [
        {"id": "corner001", "src": "corner001.png"},
        {"id": "corner002", "src": "corner002.png"},
        ...
        {"id": "corner047", "src": "corner047.png"}
    ],
    "edge": [
        {"id": "edge001", "src": "edge001.png"},
        {"id": "edge002", "src": "edge002.png"},
        ...
        {"id": "edge216", "src": "edge216.png"}
    ]
}
```

The JSON is a catalog of the files that exist somewhere in a directory so that the app doesn't have to manually read that directory to get a list of the files.

The 3 categories and the arrays of numbers are directly related. (JSON category 1 = `set[0]`, etc). The numbers in the sub-arrays are within the range of the number of files listed in the JSON, per category.

I want to correlate, say, 34 (from `set[1][0]` above) to the direct entry, in the JSON file (category 2, file 34). `set[1][34]` should map to `files['corner'][34]` so I can get the data there.

I've been doing this using nested `for` loops, nested `forEach` functions, etc. Basically, I've been looping thru `set[category]` then sub-looping thru `category[entry]` to get that specific line from the JSON file.

But I can't help but think... Is there a better way to do this using some kind of `map` method/function?

Comment: Let us see what is not working. Kindly share your code

Comment: And please also share the structure of your `JSON`.

Comment: @KarthickManoharan I have things working fine. It's a conceptual question cuz it seems inefficient to use nesting loops.

Comment: If the file numbering is 1 to x, then you can use the index, which is file number - 1.

Comment: @OriDrori Which is what I've been doing with nested loops. The question is whether or not there's a better way.

Comment: And this is why you have to add some code :)

Comment: So `set[1][0] = 34` should map to `files['corner'][34]`??

Comment: @fubar yes. But I was trying to avoid using the word "map" even tho that's what it is. . . will change the op.

Comment: Okay so to confirm, would you like to be able to specify the `set` path (`set[1][0]`) to be able to retrive a given file object?

Comment: @fubar yes, and I need to do it for each number in `set`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this with `Array.prototype.map`. First you need to get the keys of the Object you get parsing your `JSON`.

```
let keys = Object.keys(o);
```

Lets say `o` be the Object with the categories then you can `map` it like follows.

```
set = set.map((a, i) => a.map(e => o[keys[i]][e - 1]));
```

Then you can easily access by `set[1][0]`.

**Working DEMO**

```js
let o = {
  "main": [{
      "id": "main001",
      "src": "main001.png"
    },
    {
      "id": "main002",
      "src": "main002.png"
    },
    {
      "id": "main098",
      "src": "main098.png"
    }
  ],
  "corner": [{
      "id": "corner001",
      "src": "corner001.png"
    },
    {
      "id": "corner002",
      "src": "corner002.png"
    },
    {
      "id": "corner047",
      "src": "corner047.png"
    }
  ],
  "edge": [{
      "id": "edge001",
      "src": "edge001.png"
    },
    {
      "id": "edge002",
      "src": "edge002.png"
    },
    {
      "id": "edge216",
      "src": "edge216.png"
    }
  ]
};
let set = [
  [2, 1, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3]
];
let keys = Object.keys(o);
set = set.map((a, i) => a.map(e => o[keys[i]][e - 1]));
console.log(set);
console.log(set[1][0]);
```

Comment: So where I was doing nested loops, you're doing nested maps. I'm going to have to dissect this with the docs, but it seems to be what I figured was out there, but couldn't see. Thanks for the reply!